# Where does PHP get its settings if no configuration file is loaded?

Tags: php

I have set up PHP 5.3.10 on a RHEL 4 server.

When I ran `php -i | grep "Loaded"` it returned

`Loaded Configuration File => (none)`

It's OK with that setup. PHP is working the way we needed it to. I just need to know, if no php.ini is being used, where does PHP get all its settings? Thanks.

Update: I realized this after I hit submit. Sorry, how do I move this to Stack Overflow? -_-

Update 2: Result of `php --ini`:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`

Comment: Someone with enough Rep will probably migrate (move) it to SO.  If you want, you can click the "Flag" link at the bottom of your question, then select "Other" and type a message asking a moderator to move it.

Comment: @KevinFegan Thanks, I just flagged it.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no php configuration file loaded it just takes the default values. Please check the documentation to have the list of the default values :

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on your server setup.

It could be (depending on PHP version) that the PHP configuration is controlled from within the Apache configuration files:
[How to change configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

You can use the phpinfo() function to view your PHP configuration settings (including the config file directory). Create a file called info.php (for example in the folder that is the "DocumentRoot"), and edit the file to contain the following code:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

So, if your domain is:

```
http://example.com
```

And your "DocumentRoot" is:

```
".../www" or  ".../public_html"
```

Place the file in that folder and then using a browser, go to:

```
http://example.com/info.php
```

This should show you all the settings.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to tell that this server doesn't have any web server and we're just using the CLI. I appreciate the help though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you got to understand that command line PHP uses another `php.ini`. And Apache (or NGINX etc.) module uses another `php.ini`.

You may try use more reliable command: `php --ini` rather than `php -i` to make sure it's not loading any configs.

Usually it loads `php.ini` from `/etc/php5`

If the command is not showing you anything, so you may try to add that file (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`) manually and check.

In `RedHat` it may be directly on `/etc/` directory.

Comment: I did `php --ini`, the results are on my question. The machine doesn't have a web server. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to create /etc/php.ini or /etc/php5/cli/php.ini manually?

Comment: No, because we're not trying to do that. I'm actually just asking where PHP gets its settings if there's no php.ini being used. Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, because php --ini must show your correct information. Please don't forget to add your own answer if you fix this by yourself.